# adapter Ecto.Adapters.Postgres was not compiled

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am not able to create my Phoenix project. Would love some advice on how to fix it.

Setup details:

- Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.1] [source] [64-bit]
  [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
- Elixir 1.7.3 (compiled
  with Erlang/OTP 20)
- Mix 1.7.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 20)
- Ecto v3.0.0

I am following the [Phoenix Up and Running](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/up_and_running.html#content) to make an app.

```
mix phx.new hello
cd hello
mix ecto.create
```

last command gives me:

```
 == Compilation error in file lib/hello/repo.ex ==
 ** (ArgumentError) adapter Ecto.Adapters.Postgres was not compiled, ensure it is correct and it is included as a project dependency
     lib/ecto/repo/supervisor.ex:71: Ecto.Repo.Supervisor.compile_config/2
     lib/hello/repo.ex:2: (module)
     (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
     (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:206: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

I have postgres installed. I have postgres super user.

Comment: In your projects `mix.exs` file. Do you have something like `{:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}` in your dependencies?

Comment: yes, I changed to {:postgrex, ">= 0.10.0"}   after reading in some blogs, but no luck :(

Comment: Did you include `ecto_sql` as a dependency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have `phoenix_ecto` 3.5.0 in your dependencies? Downgrading to 3.4.0 worked for me as a temporary fix until I figure out the underlying issue.

To force a downgrade:

1. Run `mix deps.clean --all`
2. Delete your `mix.lock` file
3. Update your `mix.exs` file limiting the `phoenix_ecto` version. Find the appropriate line and replace with:
   `{:phoenix_ecto, ">= 3.2.0 and < 3.5.0"},`
4. Run `mix deps.get`

Alternatively, if you are just starting with Phoenix, you could use version 1.4 to learn, which will be released soon and does not have this issue.

First remove your current local Phoenix archive:

`mix archive.uninstall phx_new`

Then, to install the latest **development version**, follow the instructions in https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/installer/README.md

Comment: Decided to go for the uninstall and instal new RC method as I am just starting out. Thanks

Answer (score 29):

Starting with Ecto 3.0, `Ecto.Adapters.Postgres` is not shipped with Ecto by default, therefore you have to add `ecto_sql` to the Mixfile dependencies:

```
###########
# mix.exs #
###########
defp deps do
  [
    # (...)
    {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0-rc.1"},
    {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}
  ]
end

# Feeling skittish about dependencies, 
# I usually do this instead of simply 
# doing `mix deps.get`:

$ mix deps.clean --all
$ mix do deps.get, compile
```

(*[The Ecto github repo v3.0.0 tree](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/tree/v3.0.0) recommends `{:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"}`, but the latest release is the `3.0.0-rc.1`) therefore it won't work as of now. Interestingly there is no `3.0.0-rc.1` tag in the repo, but [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/3.0.0-rc.1/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html) already refers to that and it also works with `mix`.*)

...or, as [Yufrend recommends in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53063825/1498178), if you are starting a new Phoenix project, use < 1.4.0 packages.

---

See José Valim's [“A sneak peek at Ecto 3.0” series](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2018/10/a-sneak-peek-at-ecto-3-0-breaking-changes/) where the first post explains the breaking changes in Ecto 3.0:

> ## Split Ecto into `ecto` and `ecto_sql`
>
> Ecto 3.0 will be broken in two repositories: `ecto` and `ecto_sql`.
>   Since Ecto 2.0, an increased number of developers and teams have been
>   using Ecto for data mapping and validation, without a need for a
>   database. However, adding Ecto to your application would still bring a
>   lot of the SQL baggage, such as adapters, sandboxes and migrations,
>   which many considered to be a mixed message.
>
> In Ecto 3.0, we will move all of the SQL adapters to a separate
>   repository and Ecto will focus on the four building blocks: schemas,
>   changesets, queries and repos. [You can see the discussion in the
>   issues tracker.](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/2558)
>
> If you are using Ecto with a SQL database, migrating to Ecto 3.0 will
>   be very straight-forward. Instead of:
>
> ```
> {:ecto, "~> 2.2"}
> ```
>
> You should list:
>
> ```
> {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"}
> ```
>
> And if you are using Ecto only for data manipulation but with no
>   database access, then it is just a matter of bumping its version.
>   That’s it!

---

UPDATE

For some reason, I also needed to add `{:plug_cowboy, "~> 1.0"}` to the Mixfile dependencies when updating a Phoenix 1.3 project and it all started working.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the new phoenix version worked for me.

Uninstall old version:

```
mix archive.uninstall phx_new
```

Install new version:

`mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.4.0-rc.2`

Answer (score 2):

### New Projects

For creating new projects with `Ecto 3.0`, it's highly recommended you upgrade to the new phoenix `1.4.x` installer:

```
$ mix archive.uninstall phx_new
$ mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.4.0-rc.2
```

---

### Existing Projects

To upgrade your existing Phoenix `1.3.x` projects to `1.4`, read the [Official Upgrade Guide](https://gist.github.com/chrismccord/bb1f8b136f5a9e4abc0bfc07b832257e) and the accompanying [announcement](https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-1-4-0-rc-released/17182).

**TLDR is that `Ecto` has been broken into sub-packages, and you need to specify them explicitly:**

> Remove your explicit `:ecto` dependency and update your `:phoenix_ecto` and `:ecto_sql` dependencies with the following versions:
>
> ```ex
> {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0-rc"},
> {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
> ```